# Difference between Apache AddType and AddHandler directives?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server

My understanding is:

- `AddHandler` - for server
- `AddType` - for client (browser)

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php4 .php4
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php4 .php4
```

But why do we need to add both? Is both needed in case of PHP? Is `AddType` needed for PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype): Maps the given filename extensions onto the specified content type
- [AddHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler): Maps the filename extensions to the specified handler

In your case it is just coincidence that the content type is equal to the name of the handler - given that there actually is a handler named `application/x-httpd-php4`. Otherwise it's just plain wrong.

Comment: But is AddType needed for PHP ?

Comment: Only if you want to use MultiViews. See http://www.php.net/manual/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.apache.multiviews

Answer (score 1):

As has been said:

1. `AddType` is used to associate file extension with a MIME-type (and therefore to change `content-type` HTTP response header)
2. `AddHandler`/`SetHandler` are used to bind file extension to a server side handler (like PHP).

It seems like using `AddType` to bind PHP handler is an obsolete way that used before `AddHandler`/`SetHandler` was introduced in Apache 1.1.0.

## A little bit of history that I could find

### There were no `AddHandler`/`SetHandler` in Apache 1.0.x

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/1.3/apache_1_0_0/src/modules/standard/mod_mime.c contains:

```
command_rec mime_cmds[] = {
{ "AddType", add_type, NULL, OR_FILEINFO, ITERATE2,
    "a mime type followed by one or more file extensions" },
{ "AddEncoding", add_encoding, NULL, OR_FILEINFO, ITERATE2,
    "an encoding (e.g., gzip), followed by one or more file extensions" },
{ "AddLanguage", add_language, NULL, OR_FILEINFO, ITERATE2,
    "a language (e.g., fr), followed by one or more file extensions" },
{ "TypesConfig", set_types_config, NULL, RSRC_CONF, TAKE1,
    "the MIME types config file" },
{ NULL }
};
```

### April 1996

[PHP/FI (PHP 2.0)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/history.php.php#history.phpfi) introduced the [Apache module version of PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/phpfi2.php#redirect). The official Apache release at that time was 1.0.5.

README from https://museum.php.net/php2/php-1.99s.tar.gz contains:

```
Step 4. (If you are NOT installing the Apache module version)
  
  Copy the php.cgi binary to your system's cgi-bin directory.  If you
  do not have access to do this and wish to install it in your own
  personal directory, you may do so, but you should set the setuid
  bit on the executable with: chmod u+s /path/php.cgi
  Setting the setuid bit is not crucial.  The benefit is that any files
  created by php will be owned by you.  This means that you can edit
  and delete such files directly.  Without the setuid bit set these
  files will be owned by the httpd user id.

Step 4. (if you are installing the Apache module version)

  Change to your Apache src directory where the mod_php.c and mod_php.h
  files should have been copied to. If they weren't which usually happens
  because of permission problems, copy these two files there manually. Edit
  your Apache Configuration file and add the EXTRA_LIBS line which was
  produced at the end of Step 3. And add:

    Module php_module mod_php.o

  to the very end of the file. Then type: ./Configure and then make to rebuild
  your Apache httpd binary. Install this binary.

  Next you need to edit your Apache conf/srm.conf file and add a line like:

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml

  This defines a new MIME, application/x-httpd-php, which will trigger the
  PHP module to parse any file ending with the .phtml extension. You can pick
  any extension you like for this.

  Now you are ready to restar your httpd server. See the Apache Module
  Notes for more details on configuring the PHP Module.
```

src/mod_php.c from https://museum.php.net/php2/php-1.99s.tar.gz contains:

```
handler_rec php_handlers[] = {
        { "application/x-httpd-php", send_parsed_php },
        { NULL }
};

module php_module = {
        STANDARD_MODULE_STUFF,
        NULL,                           /* initializer */
        php_create_conf,        /* dir config creater */
        NULL,                           /* dir merger --- default is to override */
        NULL,                           /* server config */
        NULL,                           /* merge server config */
        php_commands,           /* command table */
        php_handlers,           /* handlers */
        NULL,                           /* filename translation */
        NULL,                           /* check_user_id */
        NULL,                           /* check auth */
        NULL,                           /* check access */
        NULL,                           /* type_checker */
        NULL,                           /* fixups */
        NULL                            /* logger */
};
```

#### July 1996

`AddHandler`/`SetHandler` [was introduced](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/199607.mbox/%3CPine.SOL.3.93.960703144519.16137B-100000@acidik.organic.com%3E) in Apache 1.1.0.

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/1.3/APACHE_1_1_0/src/CHANGES contains:

```
  *) Add AddHandler command, which allows content-type-independent
     "handlers" to be defined for file extensions. These can be either
     built into Apache (such as CGI scripts or server-side includes, or
     added with the Action command). [Alexei Kosut]
```

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/1.3/APACHE_1_1_0/src/modules/standard/mod_mime.c contains:

```
command_rec mime_cmds[] = {
{ "AddType", add_type, NULL, OR_FILEINFO, ITERATE2,
    "a mime type followed by one or more file extensions" },
{ "AddEncoding", add_encoding, NULL, OR_FILEINFO, ITERATE2,
    "an encoding (e.g., gzip), followed by one or more file extensions" },
{ "AddLanguage", add_language, NULL, OR_FILEINFO, ITERATE2,
    "a language (e.g., fr), followed by one or more file extensions" },
{ "AddHandler", add_handler, NULL, OR_FILEINFO, ITERATE2,
    "a handler name followed by one or more file extensions" },
{ "ForceType", set_string_slot, (void*)XtOffsetOf(mime_dir_config, type),
    OR_FILEINFO, TAKE1, "a media type" },
{ "SetHandler", set_string_slot, (void*)XtOffsetOf(mime_dir_config, handler),
    OR_FILEINFO, TAKE1, "a handler name" },
{ "TypesConfig", set_types_config, NULL, RSRC_CONF, TAKE1,
    "the MIME types config file" },
{ NULL }
};
```

### December 2004

[Rasmus Lerdorf said](https://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=110358407015432&w=2):

> Like with most of the criticisms along these lines, they don't bother
> actually researching why something is a certain way.  There was a time
> when there was no AddHandler directive.  Addtype was the way you did
> this.  Since AddType works with every version of Apache I never saw a
> reason to change this even after AddHandler was added since it is purely
> academic in nature.

See also https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36772.

### June 2008

`AddType` [was replaced](http://git.php.net/?p=doc/en.git;a=blobdiff;f=install/unix/apache2.xml;h=86ecb0c7e36731a530dbde403c500c490fa5001b;hp=b4425537b1c8ad00dfea23d8a9136c1f80b0fa2e;hb=c99de21eac784e81c08b0a2f05087e2d804267b8;hpb=109ef75d6a93a9aa7f27cd769edcfc109b9093b9) to `SetHandler`/`AddHandler` in [PHP installation guide for Apache 2.x](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php) for [security reasons](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45229).

See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php#92797.

P.S.: but [PHP installation guide for Apache 1.3.x](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache.php) still contains `AddType` (and it seems like obsolete way too).

Comment: This is wrong! AddType was **NOT** replaced by AddHandler. AddType is still correct unless Set/AddHandler isn't set. If Handler is set, it takes precedence over the media-type.

Comment: You are wrong. AddType was replaced in PHP installation guide for Apache 2.x. See -   https://github.com/php/doc-en/commit/c99de21eac784e81c08b0a2f05087e2d804267b8 Read all links to understand.

Comment: Ah ok, I've read it as: the manual says that it got replaced ...

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of confusion and answers wrt. mod_php above are even wrong or refer to modified/mangled source code of mod_php.

Basically when a request comes in, apache httpd determines what file it refers to and asks mod_mime to set the `content_type` (AddType) and other metadata like `handler` (SetHandler, AddHandler) of the request based on the file. After this httpd asks "each" module to handle the request. For this it passes the request's `handler-name` (see [AddHandler/SetHandler](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler)) to the module, and if not set, the `content_type` (i.e. the `media-type` in [AddType](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype)) to the module (so from the POV of the module's request handler, the media-type becomes the handler-name as you can see in [ap_invoke_handler(request_rec *r)](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/server/config.c#L420). So:

*Take away 1)* **SetHandler takes precedence over AddType**, but using AddType does not hurt as long as SetHandler isn't set for the related file extension. But using AddType may be used in addition to set the MimeType of the file (unless apache httpd falls back to the handler name, if it is not set), e.g. if a directory view gets generated (MultiView shows it per default in the Description column).

When the request handler of the module gets called, it just looks, at the passed string (i.e. either handler-name or content_type) and decides, whether to process it. According to [php_handler(request_rec *r)](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c#L616)) it accepts `application/x-httpd-php`, or `application/x-httpd-php-source`, or `php-script` as handler-name (see [defines](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c#L60)). For everything else it declines processing the file, which is basically a noop.

*Take away 2)* Unless you use a modified version of mod_php, it is probably the best to **use `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php ...` or `AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps ...`** unless one needs to overwrite an [inherited] SetHandler/AddHandler directive or does not want, that mod_php handles the file but wants the correct MimeType, etc.. The **media-type will be used as handler-name, if a handler-name is not set**.

*Take away 3)* Using **AddType** ... results into a **little bit more cpu cycles**, because before passing the content type to the module's request handler, the `ap_invoke_handler()` tries to strip off any ";.*" suffix as well as trailing spaces. But unless one has a very slow CPU, one shouldn't notice it (even when measured properly) in production environments, because other "noise" like context switching, network, etc. cause a lot more, much bigger delays.

For completeness, if you wonder, how mod_mime handles AddType and AddHandler: it uses the same [metadata structure](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/http/mod_mime.c#L61) for both. Each metadata structure gets hashed by the given extension (see [add_extension_info(...)](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/http/mod_mime.c#L284)). Both (i.e. handler-name as well as media-type) get set to the request when asked (see [find_ct(request_rec *r)](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/modules/http/mod_mime.c#L929) ).